# A generic error occurred in GDI+ in Telerik Reporting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, telerik

I was trying to display the image from `Database` in Telerik Reporting by using `Picture Box` but I got an unexpected error **A generic error occurred in GDI+**

**Note:** The Image I was trying to display is in `Base64` Format

Here's my code **ByDepositSlip.cs** :

```
public ByDepositSlip(int? TypeID, int? YearOF)
    {
        //
        // Required for telerik Reporting designer support
        //
        InitializeComponent();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection.MyConn()))
        {
            var query = @"dbo.sp_Reports " + TypeID + ", " + YearOF + "";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query,con);
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            var ImageString = "";
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

            dt.Columns.Add("ParticipantName");
            dt.Columns.Add("LGU");
            dt.Columns.Add("fileName");
            dt.Columns.Add("region");
            dt.Columns.Add("ORNumber");
            dt.Columns.Add("region_code");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[0] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(0));
                dr[1] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(1));
                dr[2] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(2));
                dr[3] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(3));
                dr[4] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(4));
                dr[5] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(5));
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            CountResult.Value = "Total Number of Participants : " + 
            Convert.ToString(dt.Rows.Count);

            this.tbl_Participants.DataSource = dt;
        }

        //dt = query.GetDataTable(Connection.MyConn());


        //
        // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
        //
    }
```

The Properties on **ByDepositSlip.cs[Design]**

PictureBox :

- **Value:** =Fields.fileName
- **Sizing:** ScaleProportional

and so with the other fields with their respective values.

[image]

**Stack Trace:**

> [ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.]
>      System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString(String text, Font font, SizeF layoutArea, StringFormat stringFormat, Int32& charactersFitted, Int32& linesFilled) +627452  Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ProcessingElement.MeasureErrorItem(IMeasureContext context) +282
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.LayoutElement.Measure(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +67
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6(ITableCell cell) +66
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Table.ForEachCell(Action`1 action) +139
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Table.MeasureDataItemContent(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableClientSize) +371
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.DataItem.MeasureContent(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableClientSize) +87
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.LayoutElement.MeasureCore(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +124
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.VisualElement.MeasureCore(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +98
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ProcessingElement.MeasureCore(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +37
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.AbsolutePositionLayout.MeasureChildItems(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableClientSize) +199
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.AbsolutePositionLayout.MeasureContent(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableClientSize) +36
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportSectionBase.MeasureContent(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableClientSize) +90
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.LayoutElement.MeasureCore(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +124
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.VisualElement.MeasureCore(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +98
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ProcessingElement.MeasureCore(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +37
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.StackLayout.MeasureContent(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableClientSize) +273
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Group.MeasureContent(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableClientSize) +99
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.LayoutElement.MeasureCore(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +124
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.VisualElement.MeasureCore(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +98
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ProcessingElement.MeasureCore(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +37
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.StackLayout.MeasureContent(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableClientSize) +273
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report.MeasureContent(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableClientSize) +242
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.LayoutElement.MeasureCore(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +124
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.VisualElement.MeasureCore(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +98
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ProcessingElement.MeasureCore(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +37
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.LayoutElement.Measure(IMeasureContext context, SizeRF availableSize) +67
>      Telerik.Reporting.Paging.PhysicalPageLayout.PhysicalPageMeasurement.MeasureReport(Report report, IMeasureContext measureContext) +58
>      Telerik.Reporting.BaseRendering.RenderingExtensionBase.Render(Report report, Hashtable renderingContext, Hashtable deviceInfo, CreateStream createStreamCallback, EvaluateHeaderFooterExpressions evalHeaderFooterCallback) +507
>      Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor.RenderCore(ExtensionInfo extensionInfo, IList`1 reports, Hashtable deviceInfo, IRenderingContext renderingContext, CreateStream createStreamCallback) +1390
>      Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.ReportPageOperation.RenderReport(String format, IList`1 processingReports, Hashtable deviceInfo, IRenderingContext renderingContext) +126
>      Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.ReportRenderOperation.PerformOperationOverride() +287
>      Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.BasicHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +250
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +508
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +92